# Magento 1.9 what is skulink tag in product description

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a Magento project where they use skulink that looks something like this `{{skulink sku='PowerOptions' text='power options'}}`.

It creates an `<a>` element with a link a category page that displays power cables. The thing is, I don't know how the skulink works, like where do I get the sku name to create this link in the first place. I don't know what it's called and all my searching online has turned up nothing.

Can someone let me know what this is and how to use it? I would ask the people who's site I am working on, but they can sometimes take days to respond to questions, and I would like to work on this sooner.

BTW, I need to figure out what it's called because it is not updating with canonical URL like it's supposed to so I need to be able to fix that issue.

Comment: There is no such thing in vanilla Magento. If you have no idea about where this could coming from try `grep -r "skulink" ./` on CLI in your webroot (or, `grep -r "skulink" ./app/code/`). The result should help you to find out, what this is and probably what it is supposed to be.

Comment: It must be an extension. You can use `grep` like above comment or check all extensions one by one. Most likely extension name is "skulink"